# How to fast insert new 'pipe operator' in Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

I have been using the `ctrl + shift + m` shortcut to insert well known `%>%` pipe operator.
Since the release of R version 4.1.0 and adding a new `|>` to `base`, I wonder is the corresponding shortcut available in Rstudio?

Comment: It's the same shortcut. If you install the latest version of the IDE, and go to the Global Options window, select "Code" and you'll see an option for "use native pipe operator, |>". Select that for the shortcut to take effect.

Comment: but i cant mark this as 'accepted'... could you place your comment as a answer?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's the same shortcut. If you install the latest version of the IDE, and go to the Global Options window, select "Code" and you'll see an option for "use native pipe operator, |>". Select that for the shortcut to take effect.

[image]

Comment: Is there no way to have a shortcut for both pipes at the same time?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: Is there a way to have a short cut with RGui too?

Comment: Not to my knowledge

Comment: @qdread maybe you could check my recently posted answer below where I show how to add customized shortcuts (using as example the native pipe of R) in RStudio.

Comment: Note that you have to restart R for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

one option that works okay is to add a snippet to your code snippets if you're an rstudio user. You'd then need to hit the snippet name and then tab complete it. The ${0} then drops your cursor one whitespace away from the pipe so you save a keystroke there:

```
snippet p
  |> ${0}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you have to press SPACE before to type `p + Tab`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for having shortcuts for both native and magrittr pipes in RStudio (only): addings.

You can get a very detailed description of how **addinexamples** package works in https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/

**Important**: this solution is only valid in RStudio.

Instructions:

1. Install the **addinexamples** package from the fork on my profile: https://github.com/LuisLauM/addinexamples by running:

> devtools::install_github(repo =
> "https://github.com/LuisLauM/addinexamples")

2. Go to Tools --> Modify keyboard shortcuts

[image]

3. Find out the field **Insert |>** (tip: you can sort the list by clicking the headers of the shortcut table).

[image]

4. Remapping the shortcut with the key combination that you want (tip: it seems that not all the combinations are allowed. For instance, I try with `Ctrl + Shift + ,` but it didn't work, then `Ctrl + Shift + Space` did).

You can always fork, edit and compile the **rstudioaddins** package in order to have your own customized shortcuts. You can use my forked version as a guide to determine what files you had to modify. The package allows to create interactive addins, so it is very powerfull.